# Where is jenkins config in windows (in order to migrate from windows to linux)?

Tags: jenkins

I have downloaded tomcat 8. Then I  download jenkins.war file. I deploy it and **configure well**. I have created maven projects, jobs to build project and etc.

**Everything works well!** But I **can't** find where is stored my configuration? I want to migrate configuration from Windows to CentOS.

There is no config in the following location:

```
C:\Users\{user}\.jenkins
```

[image]

I move everything from **C:\Users{user}.jenkins** to **/root/.jenkins/**  but nothing happens. in linux I cant manage to migrate config.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the location using process monitor.

[image]

It is in **C:/windows/system32/config/systemprofile/.jenkins/**